# Java - BitSet Replacement

Tags: java

In my code I am trying to get if a number exist in the hashmap or not. My code is following:

```
BitSet arp = new BitSet();

for i = 0 to 10 million

HashMap.get (i)

if number exist
arp.set(i , true)

else
arp.set(i , false)
```

After that from bitset I get if number i exist or not. However, I found this bitset operation is quite slow (tried with `string = string + 0/1` also, more slower). Can anybody help me how to replace this operation with a faster one.

Comment: Can you show us your _actual_ code?  ...Or at least, not this pseudocode.

Comment: -1 for providing just pseudo code. Why didn't you just publish the Java code?

Comment: @home, my code is much longer and extracting required code will take time :)

Comment: But you could have provided an example that compiles...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is really difficult to read clearly, but I suspect you're just trying to set bits in the `BitSet` that are keys from your `HashMap`?

In that case, your code should just be more or less

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet(10000000);
for (Integer k : map.keySet()) {
  bits.set(k);
}
```

Even if this wasn't what you meant, as a general rule, `BitSet` is blazing fast; I suspect it's the *rest* of your code that's slow.

Comment: @Arpssss: Eh?  The code you've provided in your question doesn't even compile.  "if number exist" is not valid Java syntax.

Comment: But I have bits.set(k, true)/ bits.set(k, false)

Comment: Yes, I noticed.  That's the problem.  You should give us the _actual_ code, not pseudocode.  In any event, there's no reason you should be setting bits to false, nor should you be iterating from 1 to 10 million anyway; you should only be iterating over the `HashMap`'s keyset.

Comment: +1 to "BitSet is blazing fast; I suspect it's the rest of your code that's slow."

Comment: Agreed, why iterate.  The default value of every bit in a bitself is false, unless you set it to true explicitly.  So iterating over your map keys is the most efficient possibly way to turn on the bits that need turning on.

Answer (score 2):

If you provided your actual relevant code, we could have found some performance errors in the first place. But assuming your code is ok and you *profiled your application* to make sure that the `BitSet` operations are actually slow:

If you have enough memory space available, you can always just go for a `boolean[]` instead of a `BitSet`.

`BitSet` internally uses `long[]` to store the separate bits, so it's very good memory-wise, but can sometimes be a little bit too slow.